# Entity Framework migration debug x86 build

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Fail build image

[image: 1]

I'm trying to get build for x86 platform but I can't.

When I try to get it for any cpu, I can get it. I need to get build on x86

Comment: ProjectX.WpfApp project need to be rebuild as a X86 project.  Make sure you can project settings and then do clean build.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem even though I made x86 from the configuration manager and got the build.

Comment: All the project reference4d by main project also need to be rebuilt.  Not just the main project.